# Are any formal systems based upon the idea of "iterated characterization pushing" currently in existence? If not, is anyone working on them?

Tags: higher-category-theory, foundations, type-theory, axioms

I had an idea in regards to the design of formal systems with foundational aspirations.

To convey the idea, let's talk a bit about the second-order Peano axioms. The way these axioms work, we have a base type $\mathbb{N}$ together with a  distinguished function $S : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and a special element $0 : \mathbb{N}$. Now, we'd like to declare the pointed monounary algebra $(\mathbb{N},S,0)$ to be initial among pointed monounary algebras, but this can't be expressed directly in the language of second-order logic, so instead we add some further axioms "by hand" to express initiality. These include $S(x) \neq 0$ and $x \neq y \rightarrow S(x) \neq S(y)$, which ensure that the package $(\mathbb{N},S,0)$ doesn't satisfy any extra equations that it shouldn't, and of course the principle of induction, which ensures that $(\mathbb{N},S,0)$ doesn't have any extra elements that it shouldn't.

Okay, but what if we had more expressive power? In that case, we could postulate the existence of an initial pointed monounary algebra directly, and the structural integrity of our natural numbers would be derived, not from axioms like the principle of induction, but rather from the initiality of the relevant structure. Things like the principle of induction would then be provable from this initiality, without the need for any "special pleading" so-to-speak.

And, indeed, that's what NNO's (e.g. in topos theory) are all about!

Let's talk about ETCS for a moment. Recall that Lawvere's ETCS basically says that $\mathbf{Set}$ is a well-pointed topos satisfying choice. Included is an axiom that that there exists an NNO. Things that used to be axioms about $\mathbb{N}$, like mathematical induction, and statements like $S(x) \neq 0$, now become consequences of the initiality assumption. Let's call this *characterization pushing.*

> **Definition.** *Characterization pushing* is an informal term that means making a change from one formal system (designed to understand a structure $X$) to another formal system designed to understand the universe in which $X$ dwells. The idea is that what used to be a list of axioms peculiar to $X$ can then be replaced in one fell swoop by a single axiom asserting that $X$ is initial, or terminal, or otherwise characterized by an appropriate correspondence. We thereby do away with long lists of axioms about the internal structure of $X$ by leveraging the added expressive facilities gained by moving to a larger universe that can see the deeper significance of $X$'s existence.

Now notice that once we've moved to ETCS, the same issues seem to reassert themselves. If our goal is to try to understand $\mathbf{Set}$ using using ETCS, then we find ourselves falling into the same trap as before. What we want to say is probably that $\mathbf{Set}$ has all small coproducts, and a special object denoted $1$. These observations, together with an initiality assumption, serve to characterize $\mathbf{Set}$. And yet by adopting the ETCS viewpoint, we ignore this initiality and instead start writing down axioms that $\mathbf{Set}$ ought to satisfy internally (it has products, exponential objects, a subobject classifier, etc.). Okay, why not perform *another* characterization push?

Following this line of thought to its logical conclusion, it's probably worth creating formal systems based on "iterated characterization pushing" in which no universe is ever fixated on. The structural integrity of each universe comes from its initiality (or otherwise) from the viewpoint of the next universe, which is known to behave appropriately due its initiality (or otherwise) from the viewpoint of the next universe.

For example, one idea would be to try axiomatizing the sequence of universes $$(\infty,0)\mathbf{Cat} \in (\infty,1)\mathbf{Cat} \in (\infty,2)\mathbf{Cat} \in \cdots$$ using hopefully very simple axioms of the following form:

> **Axiom Schema $n$.** The structure $(\infty,n)\mathbf{Cat}$ is an $(\infty,n+1)$ category and can be characterized as an object of $(\infty,n+1)\mathbf{Cat}$ by the following universal property: {whatever, depends on $n$}.

The idea is that our formal system consists of one of these schemas for each natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If possible, we try to avoid assuming things like existence of products, exponential objects, W-types, etc. and we try to build these by hand using the universal properties of each universe. We ask questions like: can we prove that $(\infty,0)\mathbf{Cat}$ has products? Exponential objects? Does dependent type theory work properly in these universe we've just built?

Anyway, personally I wouldn't know where to start creating these kinds of formal systems. I just don't know enough higher category theory. But it seems possible that others are working on this kind of stuff, so I'm hopeful that there's work in this direction.

> **Question.** Are any formal systems based upon the idea of "iterated characterization pushing" currently in existence? If not, is anyone working on them? If so, who should one contact to learn about current progress in this direction?

Comment: In your paragraph on arithmetic, you call it "second-order logic" but you are really talking about first-order logic. Second-order logic *can* express the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is initial, in fact, that's just the second-order version of induction.

Comment: Next, I was not aware that the purpose of topos theory is to characterize set theory. Where did you get that idea from? Anyhow, to say that "$\mathbf{Set}$ has all small coproducts" you are already assuming a background notion of smallness, so you should address that.

Comment: And lastly, your ideas have popped up in various forms in the past, for instance in the form where people say "let's have a chain of ever stronger extensions of arithmetic to overcome Gödel incompletness". Of course, someone then asks "is there one more element after the chain?", and someone even smarter says "and is this a computable sequence?", and we're back to where we started. So you can lookup work on infinite chains of extensions of PA.

Comment: My point is that your proposed setup, which is rather more semantic than syntactic (but that's beide the point) will suffer the same faith. Which is not to say that the observation you made isn't useful (it is!), namely that many structures may be characterized by the role they play in a wider context (a category, a universe of sets). Category theorists like to express this role by a universal property, and that works very well. Type theorists prefer an induction principle, and that too works very well. So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @AndrejBauer, I've done my best to improve it. But honestly, I thought it was pretty clear before the changes. It's different to infinite chains of extensions of PA. In that context, you have a formally defined operator on theories of arithmetic, and you can iteratively apply it to get stronger and stronger theories in the same language. In this context, the characterization pushing (probably not the best term) is an informal concept forever suggesting a way to remove the artifice from our system by changing the "universe" we're axiomatizing. The idea is that by taking this limit to ...

Comment: ... infinity, we can avoid ever stating an axiom with any artifice about it. *Every* axiom with any teeth in it is a universal property, and the universe in which that universal property is expressed is itself not really axiomatized directly, but rather characterized by yet another universal property in larger universe. So for example, if we decide to focus on axiomatizing the $(\infty,r)\mathbf{Cat}$ hierarchy using characterization pushing, then the idea would be to describe $(\infty,0)\mathbf{Cat}$ by its place in $(\infty,1)\mathbf{Cat},$ which is described by its place in ...

Comment: ... $(\infty,2)\mathbf{Cat},$ etc. That way, we avoid writing down any axioms with any semblance of artifice about them, and (hopefully) create systems that feel especially natural, persuasive, and easy-to-use.

Comment: I did read your question, and I think the edits you made make it better. But let me just ask: your infinite sequence of universe that achieves the "forever characterization pushing" (whatever that means), is it too initial in some further "characterization pushing"? If yes, you're not done. If not, there seems to be an arbitrariness in your approach after all. Don't get me wrong, I understand what you're asking for, and I myself promoted the point of view that first-order arithmetic is just broken, precisely for the reasons you lay out. But this business of infinite ascent just won't cut it.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, I think the answer to your question is that yes, the formal system described isn't done, in some sense, because you'd always have a bigger universe in which the whole tower you've built could potentially be characterized by a universal property. But, that's okay. For starters, as long as we have a universe for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there's no largest universe, you never get stuck, and therefore every "elementary" result in mathematics should hopefully be provable in this framework, including e.g. the Peano axioms. If you want more power, one idea would definitely be to...

Comment: ... have yet a another universe chain for the ordinals above $\omega$. But ordinary mathematics probably doesn't need these extra extensions. I'll also remark that AFAIK Godel's incompleteness phenomena don't have much impact on everyday mathematics. The barrier to the formalization of everyday math is not incompleteness issues, it's that mathematicians won't invest time learning a formal system unless it's seriously elegant, natural, and insightful. I think the iterated characterization pushing could help with this. And sure, it doesn't help much with Godel issues. But I think that's okay.

Comment: @goblin Bad news: The naïve approach you're taking to higher category theory doesn't work.  Things are just really complicated.  You can characterize some properties, but they don't give you all of the operations you might be interested in.  I proved Yoneda's lemma for (∞,n)-categories in a paper last year, and the characterization of (∞,n)-Cat as say iterated Complete Segal Spaces doesn't really get you much closer to that goal.  A major open problem is how to characterize higher Grothendieck fibrations strongly enough to be able to prove straightening/unstraightening in that setting.

Comment: Consider the fact that the only known proof of straightening/unstraightening for general ∞,1-Grothendieck fibrations is in Higher Topos Theory, and the proof is very complicated.

Comment: @HarryGindi, maybe Yoneda's lemma could be an axiom? Notice that the $n$th axiom schema involves the concept of an $(\infty,n)$-category. Perhaps this appropriate definition of an $(\infty,n)$-category is that the $(\infty,n)$-Yoneda lemma works in that context.

Comment: @goblin In higher category theory, axioms get replaced with data. The 'axioms' for (∞,1)-categories intrinsically would be a giant infinite list of coherences.  It's not a workable approach.  See for example the thesis of Nick Gurski (an Algebraic Theory of Tricategories) https://gauss.math.yale.edu/~mg622/tricats.pdf .  This is just for tricategories, and ∞,1-categories would be even harder to work with by means of explicit axioms.

Comment: @HarryGindi, well, yes. Indeed, that's exactly my point! Here's, I'll show you a toy model. Let $(X,\lesssim)$ denote a set with a binary relation. I claim that $(X,\lesssim)$ is a preordered set iff it satisfies the "left Yoneda lemma", namely $$x \lesssim y \iff (a \lesssim x \implies a \lesssim y).$$ The interesting direction, for our purposes, is the backward direction. For reflexivity, take $y := x$, in which case the formula reads $$x \lesssim x \iff (a \lesssim x \implies a \lesssim x)$$ which gives reflexivity.

Comment: For transitivity, note that we can weaken the equivalence to an implication, like so:
$$x \lesssim y \implies (a \lesssim x \implies a \lesssim y)$$
From this, we obtain $a \lesssim x \wedge x \lesssim y \implies a \lesssim y,$ which is a statement of transitivity.

Comment: @HarryGindi, here's another observation: we can deduce that composition in category theory is associative if we assume that covariant hom-functors are functorial. In particular, given morphisms $W \xrightarrow{f} X \xrightarrow{g} Y \xrightarrow{h} Z$, we have $(h \circ g) \circ f = \mathrm{Hom}(X,h \circ g)(f) = (\mathrm{Hom}(X,h) \circ \mathrm{Hom}(X,g))(f) = \mathrm{Hom}(X,h)(\mathrm{Hom}(X,g))(f)) = h \circ (g \circ f).$

Comment: Another informal term which comes to mind in this context is the [microcosm principle](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/microcosm+principle) -- the idea that a structure of type $X$ often lives naturally inside a higher structure of type $Y$, where $Y$ is itself a "categorification" of $X$.

Comment: @goblin May be the possibility of inductive definition of a universe ressembles what you are looking for ? See https://homotopytypetheory.org/2014/06/08/hiru-tdd/ for instance.